# I am getting error that "next is not a function" . The same code is working for the other source which i am preferring from one sir

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express()

//middleware
const middleware=(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('this is just a middleware in console');
    next();
}
middleware()
app.get('/about',middleware,(req,res)=>{
    res.send('hi this is about');
    console.log('about in console');

})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('hi');
})
```

please tell the reason so that i can solve it , please as soon as possible, help me.

Comment: Because you are calling it without passing in the proper arguments: `middleware()`

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is just define another middleware targeting your '/about', instead of creating a function called middleware and calling it all by itself.

A solution you could use is this:

```js
const express=require('express');
const app=express()

app.get('/about', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('this is just a middleware in console');
    next();
});
app.get('/about', (req,res, next)=>{
    res.send('hi this is about');
    console.log('about in console');
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('hi');
})
```

This way you're handling middleware logic in the middleware function above your final middleware function where you ultimately send a response back to the client.